# Whats' wrong with my code?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a password cracker for a project at school, but I've run into a problem. Here's the code:

```
dictfile = open('c:/ScienceFairDictionaryFolder/wordsEn.txt', 'r')
DictionaryWords = dictfile.readlines()

Password = "abductors"

for x in DictionaryWords:
    if x is Password:
        print("Found it!")
    else:
        print("This password can't be guessed!")
```

So everytime I run this code, I only get:

```
"This password can't be guessed!"
```

However, I made sure the word was in the dictionary I'm using, so I don't understand why the password isn't being guessed. Is there something I'm doing wrong with the code I'm using?

Comment: 1: Don't use `is` for string comparisons. Use `==`. 2: You have to remove the line ends: `if x.strip('\r\n') == Password:`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two things with your code: Use `==` for string comparisons and remove the newline (`\n`) character by replacing it.

```
dictfile = open('wordsEn.txt', 'r')
DictionaryWords = dictfile.readlines()

Password = "abductors"

for x in DictionaryWords:
    if x.replace("\n", "") == Password:
        print("Found it!")

    else:
        print("This password can't be guessed!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Stepwise description of the suggested approach:

1. Read the file content using the `read()` method instead of `readlines()`.
2. Generate a list of words using the `split()` method. This also removes the newline characters.
3. Check whether the password is in the dictionary through the `in` operator. This allows you to get rid of the `for` loop.

This snippet should get the job done:

```
with open('c:/ScienceFairDictionaryFolder/wordsEn.txt', 'r') as dictfile:
    DictionaryWords = dictfile.read().split('\n')

Password = "abductors"

if Password in DictionaryWords:
    print("Found it!")
else:
    print("This password can't be guessed!")
```